# How do I append a set to a vector?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have `[{1 2 3 4}]`. How do I append `{5 6 7 8}` so that the vector will say `[{1 2 3 4} {5 6 7 8}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same way you append any other value to a vector: `conj`

```
(let [v [#{1 2 3 4}]]
  (conj v #{5 6 7 8}))
;; gives [#{1 2 3 4} #{5 6 7 8}]
```

(Incidentally, note the `#{}` syntax. `{1 2 3 4}` is a map containing the pairs `(1 2)` and `(3 4)`, while `#{1 2 3 4}` is a set of the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4.)

Answer (score 6):

```
 (conj [#{1 2 3 4}] #{5 6 7 8})
```

Note that in your example you have not sets, but maps from long to long.

Also, note that this is not appending to the vector (vectors are immutable), but rather it is creating a new vector with the new value appended.